# Is Varanasi (ancient Kashi) mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, kashi

Is Varanasi (ancient Kashi) mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayana?

Was Varanasi (ancient Kashi) one of the places Rama visited to recover Sita on the journey to Lanka?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Varanasi was a place that Rama visited on his journey, but the city is mentioned a few times. Here are two examples:

[Sita praying to Ganga](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc423999.html):

> Returning to Ayodhya, I will offer a sacrifice of a hundred jars of wine and rice to you. I will worship all the gods dwelling on your banks and all the sacred places such as Prayaga and **Kashi**. O Sinless One, grant that Rama and Lakshmana, free from sin, completing the term of their exile, return again to Ayodhya.”

[King Dasharatha consoling Kaikeyi](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc423957.html):

> “I swear to accomplish whatever you desires. Know me to be monarch of a kingdom on which the sun never sets. The lands of Drivira, Sindhu, Sauvira, Sourashtra, Dakshinaputha, Vanga, Anga, Maghandha, Matsha, **Kashi** and Koshala together with their abundant produce and wealth are ruled by me. If you desirest any of these, tell me.